# What is the clunking sound that happens from 5 to 30 mph

Tags: noise, cv-joint, swaybar

I have a clunky rubbing noise that happens at around 5 mph, gets louder then subsides around 30 mph, sounds like the rear but that may be an illusion. When I hot he breaks, it stops, also as I said higher speeds make it disappear. I looked at the sway bar bushing and it does look like it needs to be replaced, but this sound does not seem to be related to bumps. Also to by clear it appears to be Rhythmic, with the speed of the tire.

Answer (score 1):

If it is rhythmic to the speed of the tire and stops when you brake, check the brakes.  They make noise when they need attention.

If it's a clacking type sound, likely the brake pads are worn and need to be replaced and are rattling in their seats.  You could also be missing one of the clips that holds the brake pad in place (they're poorly made little things that serve great purpose).

I would recommend a brake inspection to rule that out first.